# Unique group combinations

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

If I have 30 objects and 5 buckets that each hold 6 objects, how many times could I put the objects into the buckets without an object being in the bucket with an object it has previously been grouped with? So, for each round you would empty all of the objects from the buckets and place them into buckets again (they could be in the same bucket multiple times, just not see another object multiple times).

Edit:  20 buckets with 6 objects per bucket is better.  The original example I gave is bad.

Comment: Is this homework?  Whether or not it is, what have you tried so far and what is your thinking about it?

Comment: What you didn't say that I would assume is that the six for each bucket is selected at random.  Also I think what you mean by the question is "when is the probability that I don't put any 2 balls in the same bucket as a previous round equal to zero?"  After the second round the probability that none return is some positive number p, on the next draw the probability will decrease because each ball has now been partnered with 10 objects. At some point the restriction will lead to a contradiction.

Comment: It will not be possible to have that many different partners without one having at least one repeat partner. It is the number of rounds until the probability is zero that you are looking for L believe.

Answer (score 3):

In the first round, just put them all in random buckets. We'll call balls that ended up in the first bucket 1-balls, balls in the second bucket 2-balls, etc.

In the second round, take a 1-ball and put it in the first bucket. Now it can't have another 1-ball, so put any other ball in there. It doesn't matter which, so say it's a 2-ball. Now put another ball in. It can't be a 1- or 2-, but it doesn't matter which others, so say it's a 3-ball. Repeat for a 4-ball and a 5-ball. Now you have 5 balls in there, but no candidate for a sixth. And you can't swap out any of the balls already in there either.

So the answer is just 1 time.

Comment: Right.  I think the example was bad.  What if I had 20 buckets with 6 objects per bucket and 120 total objects?  Is there a formula that would give that answer?

Comment: An alternative way to look at the more general problem:
On round 1 put every ball in a random bucket.
On round 2, keep the 1st ball that went in each bucket in the same one. Move the second one across to the next bucket. Move the third one across by two buckets, etc.
On round 3, keep the 1st ball in each bucket in the same one. The second ball (from the 1st day) now must be moved across by two places, the third ball has to be moved across 4 places, etc.

A general formula for the places moved ith ball on the rth round would be:
(r-1)(i-1)

Comment: So if there are n balls per bucket, then the maximum places you'd need to move any ball in a round would be (r-1)(n-1). Meaning for b buckets, you need:
(b+1) = (r-1)(n-1)
So the number of rounds you can successfully complete is:
r = floor((b+1)/(n-1)) + 1

Comment: That would give me 2 rounds for the original question I asked, but you already mentioned the answer to that one is one (which I believe you are correct on).

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit sloppy.

You need to move the nth ball (r-1)(n-1) spots, which means that you b-1 = (r-1)(n-1), not b+1. 

If you rearrange that, you then have:
r = floor((b-1)/(n-1)) + 1

Which should give the correct answer

Comment: I still feel like something is off.  If I had 10 buckets and 6 spots per bucket, that gives me 2 rounds.  I haven't completely verified this yet, but shouldn't I have 4 rounds?